# Crear tabla con columnas opcionales sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas quisiera su gentil apoyo.
Estoy realizando en crear una tabla temporal en base a una sp que retorna ciertas columnas dinamicas.
yo habria creado una tabla temporal con columnas fijas
Quisiera saber si se puede crear columnas opcionales para que no ocurra ese error

```
create table #pasMS (fila int,cod_n1 varchar(100),cod_n2 varchar(100) null,style int,descripcion varchar(100),ahorro_red float,cts_red float,dpl_red float,sal_cap_red float)  
 

insert into #pasMS
                exec piv.GPIVRES01 @variables=@tvars,@filters=@tfil,@rows=@jer,@columns='"prod_capt","vars"',@config=@tconf--,@show_query=1
```

pero hay casos que ese sp retorna menos columnas y da un error.

Comment: ¿Existe la posibilidad de crear una consulta dinámica? - no comprendo por qué es necesaria la tabla temporal...o, si es necesaria la tabla "ya sea física o temporal", investigue cómo puede migrar los resultados de la consulta a una tabla - algo como un ETL. Espero sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente NO así de la forma en que lo estás planteando. Sin embargo, si puedes manejar columnas opcionales si declaras un `insert` explícito.

Conceptualmente sería algo así:

```
insert into  #pasMS (fila, cod_n1, cod_n2, style, descripcion, 
                     ahorro_red ,cts_red float, dpl_red, sal_cap_red)  
exec piv.GPIVRES01 @variables=@tvars,
                   @filters=@tfil,
                   @rows=@jer,
                   @columns='"prod_capt","vars"',
                   @config=@tconf
```

Las columnas del `insert` las debes definir en función de las que entrega el Sp, si  alguna de las llamadas del Sp, entrega solo `fila, cod_n1, cod_n` simplemente:

```
insert into  #pasMS (fila, cod_n1, cod_n2)  
exec piv.GPIVRES01 ....
```

Comment: así lo estaba haciendo pero hay muchas cosas que no devuelve lo mismo siempre puede ir una columna más o menos o igual y al momento sale error porque hay 5 columnas y sp devuelve 3 columnas o 4 o 5

Comment: Lamentablemente no hay forma, incluso intentarlo desde una sentencia dinámica es muy complicado, no hay muchas maneras de saber de antemano que datos retorna un Sp.